# Error in pubsub schema definition creating from terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, schema, google-cloud-pubsub, terraform-provider-gcp

I am creating GCP pubsub schema with terraform.

When I am creating pubsub schema manually I am directly copy paste schema in the provided field and didn't get any error.

But when I am creating schema from terraform I have to replace newline with "\n".
Is there any solution so that I don't have put "\n" in place of newline explicit.

My terraform code for pubsub schema

```
resource "google_pubsub_schema" "schema" {
  name = var.schema_name
  type = var.schema_type
  definition = var.schema_definition
}
```

Not working : Format provided by the product team, getting the error from terraform

```
syntax = "proto3";
package com.sntl.proto;
message UsageMessageProto {
  string tenantEnvId = 1;
  string correlationId = 2;
  UsageDataProto data = 3;
  message UsageDataProto {
  string identity = 1;
  string sessionId = 2;
  uint32 clientVersion = 3;
  uint64 timeStamp = 4;
  string authId = 5;
  uint64 usageCountMultiplier = 6;
  uint64 hardlimit = 7;
  string machineId = 8;
  string serviceId = 9;
  uint64 vendorId = 10;
  string logComment = 11;
}
}
```

Working : new change format replace newline with "\n":

```
\n syntax = \"proto3\"; \n package com.sntl.proto; \n message UsageMessageProto { \n string tenantEnvId = 1; \n string correlationId = 2; \n UsageDataProto data = 3; \n message UsageDataProto { \n string identity = 1; \n string sessionId = 2; \n uint32 clientVersion = 3; \n uint64 timeStamp = 4; \n string authId = 5; \n uint64 usageCountMultiplier = 6; \n uint64 hardlimit = 7; \n string machineId = 8; \n string serviceId = 9; \n uint64 vendorId = 10; \n string logComment = 11;\n}\n}\n
```

I need a solution so that I don't have to put "\n" in place of newline explicit.

Comment: Looks intended as per documentation, [check](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/pubsub_topic#example-usage---pubsub-topic-schema-settings). I want to confirm if this error happens because your pubsub definition use \n on block 1??? Also, when you are referring to the Format provided (block2) by product team .. 'syntax = "proto3" ...'  Its because you were unable to set previous definition on the first block?

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of how you can use

```
resource "google_pubsub_schema" "test_schema" {
  name       = "test-schema"
  project    = var.google_project_id
  type       = "PROTOCOL_BUFFER"
  definition = "syntax = 'proto3'; message TestSchema { string one = 1; string two = 2; string three = 3; }"
}

resource "google_pubsub_topic" "test_schema_topic" {
  name       = "test-schema-topic"
  project    = var.google_project_id
  depends_on = [google_pubsub_schema.test_schema]
  labels = {
    "name" : "test"
    "setup" : "terraform"
  }
  schema_settings {
    schema   = "projects/${var.google_project_id}/schemas/${google_pubsub_schema.test_schema.name}"
    encoding = "JSON"
  }
}

resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "test_schema_sub" {
  project    = var.google_project_id
  name       = "test-schema-sub"
  topic      = google_pubsub_topic.test_schema_topic.name
  depends_on = [google_pubsub_topic.test_schema_topic]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the show, but put the schema in a file like "messageProto.schema.json"
Then in the resource use template literal at definition:

```
   resource "google_pubsub_schema" "schema" {
      name = var.schema_name
      type = var.schema_type
      definition = "${file("./messageProto.schema.json")}"
    }
```

By this the json will be a one-liner string while you can keep the indentation and structure of the schema.